# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
List<PopularBookModel> populars = popularBookData
    .map((item) => PopularBookModel(item['title'], item['author'],
        item['price'], item['image'], item['color'], item['description']))
    .toList();
```

Result:

```
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe try explaining what you want to do, where exactly the error occurs and show some more info.

Comment: I want to make list to insert book

Comment: That list contains title, author, price, image, color, and desc. For example: Title: Miracle, Author: Dingdong, Price: $400, Image: , Color: Blue, Desc: Dingdong is blablabla

Comment: From what you described, it seems that popularBookData contains a list of Map, is that correct? If yes, which data type is on the right side of the Map, e.g. Map<String, ?> ? And could you please share also the structure of the object PopularBookModel, with all the field types you're using ?

Answer (score -1):

It look like `item` is of type `Map<String, Object>`, but the constructor of `PopularBookModel` takes specific types, most likely `String`. Try and see if this works:

```
List<PopularBookModel> populars = popularBookData
    .map((item) => PopularBookModel(
        item['title'] as String,
        item['author'] as String,
        item['price'] as String,
        item['image'] as String,
        item['color'] as String,
        item['description'] as String))
    .toList();
```

Or whatever type you expect to be there.

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code

```
class PopularBookModel {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String author;
  final String price;
  final String image;
  final String color;
  final String description;

  const PopularBookModel(
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.author,
    this.price,
    this.image,
    this.color,
    this.description
  );
}
```

After creating model, Now create a variable to use

```
late dynamic popularBookData;
late List<PopularBookModel> populars;

@override
void initState(){
  // Create your own function to fetch data from your server and define it to popularBookData
  populars = popularBookData.map((item) {
    return PopularBookModel(
      item['id'].toString(),
      item['title'].toString(),
      item['author'].toString(),
      item['price'].toString(),
      item['image'].toString(),
      item['color'].toString(), 
      item['description'].toString(),
    );
  }).toList();
}
```